# UI automation framework for Polymer websites

Tags: polymer

Is there any UI automation framework(like Selenium or Potractor) for web sites built using google's Polymer?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I haven't tried but Selenium (maybe Protractor too) should work fine. After all Web Components is just DOM. With Shadow DOM however you'd need to prefix selectors with `body /deep/`. And I don't think XPaths will work.

And, there's also [Web Component Tester](https://github.com/Polymer/web-component-tester) although that's something different, not used to test entire pages AFAICT

Answer (score 0):

Selenium does work with Polymer. However, there are some challenges with finding/working with elements within shadow doms. It seems that most buttons are exposed as are text fields. The challenge that I have run into and am still working on is testing date pickers, drop downs and lists. These element seem to be obfuscated behind a shadow dom or something similar, but the /deep/ method doesn't work to access them.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium works with polymer. I tried finding solution online but failed. Experimented and found a way which helped my testers to completely automate our application built on polymer (E-E) with Selenium.Icludes ircular picker, dropdown, tabs, lists, buttons, links, time picker and other functionalities that are custom built but were possible over time.